# Python Regex: US phone number parsing

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am a complete newbie in Regex.

I need to parse US phone numbers in a different format into 3 strings: area code (no '()'), next 3 digits, last 4 digits. No '-'.

I also need to reject (message Error):

916-111-1111 ('-' after the area code)
(916)111 -1111 (white space before '-')
( 916)111-1111 (any space inside of area code) - (916 ) - must be
rejected too

(a56)111-1111 (any non-digits inside of area code)

lack of '()' for the area code

it should OK:  '    (916)      111-1111    ' (spaces anywhere except as above)

here is my regex:

```
^\s*\(?(\d{3})[\)\-][\s]*?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})\s*$
```

This took me 2 days.

It did not fail 916-111-1111 (availability of '-' after area code). I am sure there are some other deficiencies.

I would appreciate your help very much. Even hints.

Valid:

```
'(916) 111-1111'
'(916)111-1111     '
'   (916)      111-1111'
```

INvalid:

```
'916-111-1111' - no () or '-' after area code
'(916)111 -1111' - no space before '-'
'( 916)111-1111' - no space inside ()
'(abc) 111-11i1' because of non-digits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import re
r = r'\((\d{3})\)\s*?(\d{3})\-(\d{4,5})'
l = ['(916) 111-11111', '(916)111-1111     ', '   (916)      111-1111', '916-111-1111', '(916)111 -1111', '( 916)111-1111', '(abc) 111-11i1']
print([re.findall(r, x) for x in l])

# [[('916', '111', '11111')], [('916', '111', '1111')], [('916', '111', '1111')], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the regex if you consider (1) providing easy user interface rather than asking users to modify inputs or (2) taking the numbers to a backend storage as follows:

```
"(\d{1,3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})"
```

Since you want to print the error message, the found regex groups should be rechecked according to the error messages as follows:

**Code:**

```
import re

def get_failed_reason(s):
    space_regex = r"(\s+)"
    area_code_regex = r"\s*(\D*)(\d{1,3})(\D*)(\d{3})(\D*)-(\d{4})"
    results = re.findall(area_code_regex, s)
    if 0 == len(results):
        area_code_alpha_regex = r"\((\D+)\)"
        results = re.findall(area_code_alpha_regex, s)
        if len(results) > 0:
            return "because of non-digits"
        return "no matches"
    results = results[0]

    space_results = re.findall(space_regex, results[0])
    if 0 == len(space_results):
        space_results = re.findall(space_regex, results[2])
    if 0 != len(space_results):
        return "no space inside ()"
    
    alpha_code_regex = r"(\D+)"
    alpha_results = re.findall(alpha_code_regex, results[0])
    if 0 == len(alpha_results):
        alpha_results = re.findall(alpha_code_regex, results[2])
    if 0 != len(alpha_results):
        if "(" not in results[0] or ")" not in results[2]:
            return "no () or '-' after area code"
        if 0 != len(results[-2]):
            return "no space before '-'"
        return "because of non-digits in area code"
    return "unspecified"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phone_numbers = ["916-111-1111", "(916)111-1111", "(916)111 -1111     ", "   (916)      111-1111", "(916 )111-1111", "( 916)111-1111", "- (916 )111-1111",  "(a56)111-1111", "(56a)111-1111", "(916) 111-1111    ", "(abc) 111-1111"]
    valid_regex = r"\s*(\()(\d{1,3})(\))(\D*)(\d{3})([^\d\s]*)-(\d{4})"
    for phone_number_str in phone_numbers:
        results = re.findall(valid_regex, phone_number_str)
            
        if 0 == len(results):
            reason = get_failed_reason(phone_number_str)
            phone_number_str = f"[{phone_number_str}]"
            print(f"[main] Failed:\t{phone_number_str: <30}- {reason}")
            continue
        area_code = results[0][1]
        first_number = results[0][4]
        second_number = results[0][6]
        phone_number_str = f"[{phone_number_str}]"
        print(f"[main] Valid:\t{phone_number_str: <30}- Area code: {area_code}, First number: {first_number}, Second number: {second_number}")
```

**Result:**

```
[main] Failed:  [916-111-1111]                - no () or '-' after area code
[main] Valid:   [(916)111-1111]               - Area code: 916, First number: 111, Second number: 1111
[main] Failed:  [(916)111 -1111     ]         - no space before '-'
[main] Valid:   [   (916)      111-1111]      - Area code: 916, First number: 111, Second number: 1111
[main] Failed:  [(916 )111-1111]              - no space inside ()
[main] Failed:  [( 916)111-1111]              - no space inside ()
[main] Failed:  [- (916 )111-1111]            - no space inside ()
[main] Failed:  [(a56)111-1111]               - because of non-digits in area code
[main] Failed:  [(56a)111-1111]               - because of non-digits in area code
[main] Valid:   [(916) 111-1111    ]          - Area code: 916, First number: 111, Second number: 1111
[main] Failed:  [(abc) 111-1111]              - because of non-digits
```

Note: `D` represents non-digit characters.

Comment: your code returns results for all the cases, but they're all wrong by the OP rationale

Comment: @diggusbickus Well, I updated the answer to print error messages as the OP requested.

Comment: the point wasn't printing messages but if your regex did the job. your `valid_regex` looks good but the old failed and your message (`You can simplify the regex as follows`) was misleading

Comment: @diggusbickus The original intention of my simplified regex is explained in the updated answer.